# What is the meaning of "You've never met a graph you didn't like?"

Tags: meaning, idioms, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the exclamation *"You've never met a graph you didn't like?"*?

I came across the phrase in an article that recommended things to read to help students who are too focused on exams and disconnected from the rest of the world.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This phrase, *He never met a ________ he didn't like*, is a "quip" which is used to say that the person in question is indiscriminately or excessively fond of _________, whatever that happens to be.

> He never met a beer he didn't like.

He will drink any beer, or he drinks rather a lot of beer.  He will never refuse a beer offered to him.

> He never met a graph he didn't like.

He is rather too fond of charts and graphs.  He will take every opportunity to stick a chart in the body of the text, no matter how unnecessary it may be. Or he will peruse any chart you put in front of him no matter what it presents, he is such a "data-hound".

It could be said of a politico with a hawkish outlook or the CEO of a company that makes military weapons or of a corporation that supplies military logistical support:

> He never met a war he didn't like.

It could be said of the stereotypical overweight cop on the small-town street:

> He never met a donut he didn't like.

It could be said of a narcissist:

> He never met a mirror he didn't like.

A politician who believes in minimalist government, say, or perhaps in "Social Darwinism", might say of an opponent who believes in spending on domestic social programs:

> He never met a tax he didn't like.

---

---

User Hot Licks adds the following remark (though Rogers may have said [something a little different](https://books.google.com/books?id=YeoCAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA8&dq=%22never+met+a+man+he%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiQsunK347hAhXhY98KHUS1Az4Q6AEIQjAE#v=onepage&q=%22never%20met%20a%20man%20he%22&f=false) from what has been attributed to him over the years):

It should be noted that this trope probably originated from the expression "I never met a man I didn't like", likely first uttered by American humorist and writer [Will Rogers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0380768089). In the case of Will Rogers it was likely reasonably true, but "never met a XXX I/he didn't like" quickly acquired a sarcastic sense.

Comment: I like the answer except for the political commentary.  Throwing barbs, no matter how slight, does not really aid in understanding this phrase and needlessly detracts from an otherwise good answer.

Comment: @MichaelJ. I agree. Throwing slights, no matter how barbed, etc.

Comment: The Will Rogers quote is the pattern on which all the others depend. You should probably put that first.

Comment: @Michael J:  I'm showing examples of how the phrase is actually used by politicians; it tends to get a lot of play in the political arena.

Comment: @Mitch:   I don't think that association deserves the prominent role you've suggested for it, since the question was about what the statement meant. And I would guess that the majority of speakers who use the pattern have no idea of its history.

Comment: This use of a standard phrase or cliche and replacing part of it like this is called a [snowclone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowclone) after the myth that "Eskimos have 100 words for snow" which has led to journalistic cliches of the form "X have 100 words for Y".

Comment: @TRomano , your answer associates "neo-conservative politicos"  with "hawkish outlooks" and belief in a "minimalist government" with "Social Darwinism".  Whether these associations are valid or not will be (internally, at least) debated, but the result of such a debate has no bearing on the meaning of this particular phrase.

Comment: @Michael J:  Express your views but do not edit posts that have my name on them.

Comment: @Michael J: That you removed the phrase "or a company that makes military weapons or a corporation that supplies military logistical support" smacks of censorship.  BTW, I've changed "and" to "or" in the Social Darwinism example since I did not intend to imply that the two, minimalist government and that particular philosophy, always go hand-in-hand.

Comment: @JamesRandom For snowclone, see  http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/~gpullum/EskimoHoax.pdf

Comment: @JamesRandom and whenever I hear that word I always imagine it being said by the abominable snowman in Monsters Inc...

Comment: I would like to register my offense for the perpetuation of the donut eating policeman stereotype.  (But the rest of the examples are great, and +1)

Comment: @JamesRandom: A conversation I had with my wife a few days ago: "Did it snow last night?" "Just some graupel." "What is graupel?" "You know, when you get soft hail that forms around snowflakes." "I thought that was sleet?" "That's when snow and rain mix with hail" "I guess the English really do have forty words for snow".

Comment: I´m a translator and the answer I picked was just perfect for the translation need. Great examples, good reasoning. The "political" or other content used for the examples gave me a good laugh. That´s more than I expected! Nothing to edit from my point of view. The second answer was interesting as a reference but does not solve the translation problem, the first one certainly did.

Comment: And let's not forget the joke from Mystery Science Theater 3000 - The Movie (This Island Earth), where the characters in the movie encounter aliens from a planet called Metaluna, and one of the robots (or Mike) says: "Well, I never metaluna I didn't like..."

Comment: @MichaelJ. Your edits seem biased. Let the man provide the examples he wants to. They were perefctly lucid in commuincating the meaning of the phrase. If you see a political agenda in everything, then that is on you. Sensorship is bad, mkay?